# $f(x+2xy)=f(x)+2f(xy)$; find $f(1992)$ given $f(1991)=a$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> A function $f$ satisfies
>   $$f(x+2xy) = f(x) + 2f(xy)$$
>   for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f(1991)=a$, what is $f(1992)$? Give an answer dependent on $a$.

I have seen that $f(x)=x$ is solution, but then $f(1992)$ isn't dependent on $a$...

Comment: What does "olympic" refer to? [International Mathematical Olympiad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Mathematical_Olympiads#Olympiads) (held in Hongkong in 2016, July)?

Comment: I got told that it is an problem that got asked to some maths olimpiad...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $x \neq 0$, let $y = \frac{1}{2x}$. We then see that
$$ f(x + 1) = f(x) + 2f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right). $$

Thus by induction, we can prove that
$$
  f(n) = f(1) + 2(n-1) f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$
for all natural numbers $n \geq 1$.

In particular,
$$
  f(3) = f(1) + 4f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right).
$$

But taking $x = y = 1$ in the functional equation also gives use that $f(3) = 3f(1)$, so that we get that
$$
  3f(1) = f(1) + 4f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$
which implies that
$$
  2f\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) = f(1)
$$
and so we have that
$$ f(n) = f(1) + (n - 1) f(1) = nf(1) $$
for all natural numbers $n \geq 1$.

We thus have that
$$
  a = f(1991) = 1991 f(1)
$$
and hence that
$$
  f(1992) = 1992 f(1) = \frac{1992a}{1991}.
$$

Comment: How do you prove the part by induction?

Comment: Have you tried it? For $n = 1$, the claim is just that $f(1) = f(1)$. If $f(n) = f(1) + 2(n-1)f(1/2)$ for some $n$, then $f(n + 1) = f(n) + 2f(1/2) = f(1) + 2(n-1)f(1/2) + 2f(1/2) = f(1) + 2nf(1/2)$, so the claim holds for $n + 1$ as well. So the claim holds for all $n \geq 1$ by induction.

Comment: Ohh yea thanks!

Comment: Actually the valors I put before were wrong... Could you please adapt your answer to the new values?

Comment: @DanielCortild You have been shown the process to solve the problem. You should try to advance on your own instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x,y,y'\in{\mathbb R}$ with $y\neq \frac{-1}{2}$. Let
$X=x+2xy$, $Y=\frac{y'}{1+2y}$. Then

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x)+2f(x(y+y')) &=& f(x+2x(y+y')) \\
                &=& f(X+2XY) \\
              &=& f(X)+2f(XY) \\
              &=& f(x)+2f(xy)+2f(xy') \\ 
\end{array}
$$

We deduce $f(x(y+y'))=f(xy)+f(xy')$ whenever $y\neq \frac{-1}{2}$.
It follows easily that $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ for all $u,v\in{\mathbb R}$.
So $f(ku)=kf(u)$ for any $k\in{\mathbb Z},u\in{\mathbb R}$.

So
$$
f(1992)=1992f(1)=1992\frac{f(1991)}{1991}=\frac{1992}{1991}a
$$

Comment: Actually the valors I put before were wrong... Could you please adapt your answer to the new values?

Comment: Easy : replace 1991 by 56 and 1992 by 57 ... how else can I help you ?

Answer (score 5):

With $y=0$ we find $f(0)=0$.
With $y=-1$, we find $f(-x)=f(x)+2f(-x)$, i.e., $f(-x)=-f(x)$.
Let $$S=\{\,c\in\Bbb R\mid \forall x\colon f(cx)=cf(x)\,\}.$$
So far we have $$\tag10,1,-1\in S.$$
 Clearly,
 $$\tag2x,y\in S\implies xy\in S.$$
Moreover, the functional equation immediately gives
$$\tag3 y\in S\iff 1+2y\in S.$$
As $-1\in S$, we have 
$$\tag4y\in S\stackrel{(2)}\implies -y\in S\stackrel{(3)}\implies -2y+1\in S\stackrel{(2)}\implies 2y-1\in S.$$
In particular, $$\tag51\in S\stackrel{(3)}\implies 3\in S\stackrel{(4)}\implies 5\in S\stackrel{(3)}\implies 2\in S.$$
We conclude by induction that $\Bbb N\subset S$: If $n\in\Bbb N$, then either $n$ is even, $n=2m$ with $m<n$, and $n\in S$ follows from $m\in S$ with $(2)$ and $(5)$; or $n$ is odd, $n=2m+1$ with $m<n$, so $n\in S$ by $(3)$.

In particular, $ f(1992)=1992f(1)$ and $f(1991)=1991f(1)$ so that 
$$f(1992)=\frac{1992}{1991}a.$$

Comment: Actually the valors I put before were wrong... Could you please adapt your answer to the new values?